# How to correctly use validation messages in Django Models

Tags: django, django-validation

In my Django app I am using a `PositiveSmallIntegerField` in one of my models wherein the minimum value for the field has been specified as under:

```
trc_frequency = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], ...)
```

Now what is happening is, when a value less than 1 (zero or a negative value) is being input in the form, the error message put forth by the system is to the effect:

> Ensure this value is greater than or equal to **0**.

Whereas, since the the minimum value defined for the field is "1" (one), I would prefer that the message informs the user that the minimum allowable value for the field is **1 (One)**,

to the effect:

> Ensure this value is greater than or equal to **1**.

What I have tried so far:

```
trc_frequency = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1, validators=[MinValueValidator(1, _('Must ensure this value is greater than or equal to %(limit_value)s.'))],...)
```

But still getting the minimum value specified in the error message as **1 (Zero)**. Even more surprisingly, the message text also is not getting changed from **Ensure this value is ...** to **Must ensure this value is..**. Why?

Where am I going wrong.

### Edit

**forms.py**

```
class CreateTrcFreqForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TrcFrequency
        fields = ('aud_freq_id', 'short_text', 'trc_frequency')

        widgets = {
            'freq_id': forms.TextInput(attrs={'style': 'width:40px; text-align:left'}),
            'short_text': forms.TextInput(attrs={'style': 'width:300px; text-align:left'}),
            'trc_frequency': forms.TextInput(attrs={'style': 'width:40px; text-align:right'}),
            }

##        error_messages = {
##            'trc_frequency': {
##                'min_value': _('Frequency value must be >= 1') # %(limit_value)s')
##            }
##        }
```

The `error_messages` segment has been **commented out** to test the validation in the models.py itself. But even in the form validation, with the `%(limit_value)s')` here I am getting **"0 (zero)"** and **NOT 1 (one)**. The reason why you can see the hardcoded value **"...must be >= 1')"**.

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? I just tried that and cannot replicate. 
Edit: Actually can you add your form's code I think that's where the problem is.

Comment: Using 2.0. The form is a simple `ModelForm`.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce that. Tried with 2.0/3.0. Eventually you can add validators to the form itself, maybe django is not getting the model validators correctly. I think there is still more to the code.

Comment: Added the form code (with some **explanations**).

Comment: I cannot explain this behavior, maybe try to update Django itself.